# How to play .flv(h.264 aac) file without playbin2 in gstreamer?

Tags: flv, h.264, gstreamer, gst-launch

I've got a FLV file and the gstreamer playbin2 could work well, but if I try to manually construct the pipeline, the result is negative.

Can anyone show me what's wrong with my pipeline? Or, how to construct the pipe-line to play FLV file correctly while not using the playbin2?

**The target FLV file is also uploaded to dropbox, the url is:**

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5391695/1.flv

I've try to view the dot file generated by the playbin2 method, please view it at

https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5391695/playbin2.png

The following command 1,2 both work, but command 3,4 don't work at all.

**1. media information from gst-discover**

```
gst-discoverer-0.10 1.flv 
Analyzing file:///home/gst/debug/1.flv
Done discovering file:///home/gst/debug/1.flv

Topology:
  container: Flash
    audio: MPEG-4 AAC
    video: H.264

Properties:
  Duration: 0:11:31.762000000
  Seekable: yes
  Tags: 
      duration: 691762000000
      encoder: PFree FLV Lib
      video codec: H.264
      audio codec: MPEG-4 AAC
```

**2. playbin2**

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v playbin2 uri=file:///home/gst/debug/1.flv
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: ring-buffer-max-size = 0
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: buffer-size = -1
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: buffer-duration = -1
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: use-buffering = FALSE
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: download = FALSE
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: uri = "file:///home/gst/debug/1.flv"
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: connection-speed = 0
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0: source = (GstFileSrc) source
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/GstTypeFindElement:typefind.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-flv
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/GstFlvDemux:flvdemux0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-flv
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/GstFlvDemux:flvdemux0.GstPad:video: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, width=(int)33, height=(int)10, framerate=(fraction)15/1, codec_data=(buffer)014d401fffe10019674d401f9661404012d80880000003008000000f478c18c54001000468eebc80
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-buffers = 5
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-time = 0
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-bytes = 2097152
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/GstFlvDemux:flvdemux0.GstPad:audio: caps = audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)4, framed=(boolean)true, stream-format=(string)raw, rate=(int)22050, channels=(int)2, codec_data=(buffer)139056e5a54800
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0.GstPad:sink0: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, width=(int)33, height=(int)10, framerate=(fraction)15/1, codec_data=(buffer)014d401fffe10019674d401f9661404012d80880000003008000000f478c18c54001000468eebc80
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0.GstPad:sink1: caps = audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)4, framed=(boolean)true, stream-format=(string)raw, rate=(int)22050, channels=(int)2, codec_data=(buffer)139056e5a54800
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0.GstPad:sink1: caps = audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)4, framed=(boolean)true, stream-format=(string)raw, rate=(int)22050, channels=(int)2, codec_data=(buffer)139056e5a54800
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0.GstPad:src1: caps = audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)4, framed=(boolean)true, stream-format=(string)raw, rate=(int)22050, channels=(int)2, codec_data=(buffer)139056e5a54800
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, codec_data=(buffer)014d401fffe10019674d401f9661404012d80880000003008000000f478c18c54001000468eebc80, parsed=(boolean)true, alignment=(string)au
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/GstH264Parse:h264parse0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, width=(int)33, height=(int)10, framerate=(fraction)15/1, codec_data=(buffer)014d401fffe10019674d401f9661404012d80880000003008000000f478c18c54001000468eebc80
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/GstAacParse:aacparse0.GstPad:src: caps = audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)4, framed=(boolean)true, stream-format=(string)raw, rate=(int)22050, channels=(int)2, codec_data=(buffer)139056e5a54800
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/GstAacParse:aacparse0.GstPad:sink: caps = audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)4, framed=(boolean)true, stream-format=(string)raw, rate=(int)22050, channels=(int)2, codec_data=(buffer)139056e5a54800
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/GstFaad:faad0.GstPad:sink: caps = audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)4, framed=(boolean)true, stream-format=(string)raw, rate=(int)22050, channels=(int)2, codec_data=(buffer)139056e5a54800
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/GstFaad:faad0.GstPad:src: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, codec_data=(buffer)014d401fffe10019674d401f9661404012d80880000003008000000f478c18c54001000468eebc80, parsed=(boolean)true, alignment=(string)au
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/GstCapsFilter:capsfilter0.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, codec_data=(buffer)014d401fffe10019674d401f9661404012d80880000003008000000f478c18c54001000468eebc80, parsed=(boolean)true, alignment=(string)au
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-buffers = 5
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-time = 0
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/GstMultiQueue:multiqueue0: max-size-bytes = 2097152
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstSelectorPad:sink0: always-ok = FALSE
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstInputSelector:inputselector1.GstSelectorPad:sink0: always-ok = FALSE
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstInputSelector:inputselector1: active-pad = (GstSelectorPad) sink0
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstInputSelector:inputselector0: active-pad = (GstSelectorPad) sink0
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstSelectorPad:sink0: tags = ((GstTagList*) 0xb5828cb0)
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:abin/GstAutoAudioSink:audiosink/GstPulseSink:audiosink-actual-sink-pulse: ts-offset = 0
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstAutoVideoSink:videosink/GstXImageSink:videosink-actual-sink-ximage: ts-offset = 0
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/ffdec_h264:ffdec_h2640.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, codec_data=(buffer)014d401fffe10019674d401f9661404012d80880000003008000000f478c18c54001000468eebc80, parsed=(boolean)true, alignment=(string)au
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstTee:audiotee: alloc-pad = (GstPad) src0
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstInputSelector:inputselector1.GstSelectorPad:sink0: tags = ((GstTagList*) 0xb4e30e90)
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20.GstDecodePad:src1: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20.GstDecodePad:src1.GstProxyPad:proxypad8: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0.GstGhostPad:src1: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0.GstGhostPad:src1.GstProxyPad:proxypad11: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstInputSelector:inputselector1.GstSelectorPad:sink0: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstInputSelector:inputselector1.GstPad:src: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink.GstGhostPad:audio_sink: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink.GstGhostPad:audio_sink.GstProxyPad:proxypad12: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink.GstGhostPad:audio_sink: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstTee:audiotee.GstPad:sink: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstTee:audiotee.GstPad:src0: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstTee:audiotee.GstPad:sink: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstStreamSynchronizer:streamsynchronizer0.GstPad:sink_1: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstStreamSynchronizer:streamsynchronizer0.GstPad:src_1: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:abin.GstGhostPad:sink: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:abin.GstGhostPad:sink.GstProxyPad:proxypad21: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:abin.GstGhostPad:sink: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:abin/GstQueue:aqueue.GstPad:sink: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:abin/GstQueue:aqueue.GstPad:src: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:abin/GstPlaySinkAudioConvert:aconv.GstGhostPad:sink: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:abin/GstPlaySinkAudioConvert:aconv.GstGhostPad:sink.GstProxyPad:proxypad19: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:abin/GstPlaySinkAudioConvert:aconv.GstGhostPad:sink: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:abin/GstPlaySinkAudioConvert:aconv/GstAudioConvert:conv.GstPad:src: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:abin/GstPlaySinkAudioConvert:aconv/GstAudioConvert:conv.GstPad:sink: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:abin/GstPlaySinkAudioConvert:aconv/GstAudioResample:resample.GstPad:src: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:abin/GstPlaySinkAudioConvert:aconv/GstAudioResample:resample.GstPad:sink: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:abin/GstPlaySinkAudioConvert:aconv.GstGhostPad:src: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:abin/GstPlaySinkAudioConvert:aconv.GstGhostPad:src.GstProxyPad:proxypad20: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:abin/GstAutoAudioSink:audiosink.GstGhostPad:sink: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:abin/GstAutoAudioSink:audiosink.GstGhostPad:sink.GstProxyPad:proxypad18: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:abin/GstAutoAudioSink:audiosink.GstGhostPad:sink: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:abin/GstAutoAudioSink:audiosink/GstPulseSink:audiosink-actual-sink-pulse.GstPad:sink: caps = audio/x-raw-int, endianness=(int)1234, signed=(boolean)true, width=(int)16, depth=(int)16, rate=(int)44100, channels=(int)2
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20/ffdec_h264:ffdec_h2640.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, format=(fourcc)I420, interlaced=(boolean)false, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20.GstDecodePad:src0: caps = video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, format=(fourcc)I420, interlaced=(boolean)false, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0/GstDecodeBin2:decodebin20.GstDecodePad:src0.GstProxyPad:proxypad9: caps = video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, format=(fourcc)I420, interlaced=(boolean)false, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0.GstGhostPad:src0: caps = video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, format=(fourcc)I420, interlaced=(boolean)false, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstURIDecodeBin:uridecodebin0.GstGhostPad:src0.GstProxyPad:proxypad10: caps = video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, format=(fourcc)I420, interlaced=(boolean)false, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstSelectorPad:sink0: caps = video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, format=(fourcc)I420, interlaced=(boolean)false, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstInputSelector:inputselector0.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, format=(fourcc)I420, interlaced=(boolean)false, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink.GstGhostPad:video_sink: caps = video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, format=(fourcc)I420, interlaced=(boolean)false, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink.GstGhostPad:video_sink.GstProxyPad:proxypad13: caps = video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, format=(fourcc)I420, interlaced=(boolean)false, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink.GstGhostPad:video_sink: caps = video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, format=(fourcc)I420, interlaced=(boolean)false, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstStreamSynchronizer:streamsynchronizer0.GstPad:sink_0: caps = video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, format=(fourcc)I420, interlaced=(boolean)false, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstStreamSynchronizer:streamsynchronizer0.GstPad:src_0: caps = video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, format=(fourcc)I420, interlaced=(boolean)false, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin.GstGhostPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, format=(fourcc)I420, interlaced=(boolean)false, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin.GstGhostPad:sink.GstProxyPad:proxypad17: caps = video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, format=(fourcc)I420, interlaced=(boolean)false, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin.GstGhostPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, format=(fourcc)I420, interlaced=(boolean)false, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstQueue:vqueue.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, format=(fourcc)I420, interlaced=(boolean)false, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstQueue:vqueue.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, format=(fourcc)I420, interlaced=(boolean)false, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
Redistribute latency...
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstPlaySinkVideoConvert:vconv.GstGhostPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, format=(fourcc)I420, interlaced=(boolean)false, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstPlaySinkVideoConvert:vconv.GstGhostPad:sink.GstProxyPad:proxypad15: caps = video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, format=(fourcc)I420, interlaced=(boolean)false, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstPlaySinkVideoConvert:vconv.GstGhostPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, format=(fourcc)I420, interlaced=(boolean)false, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstPlaySinkVideoConvert:vconv/GstFFMpegCsp:conv.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, format=(fourcc)I420, interlaced=(boolean)false, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstPlaySinkVideoConvert:vconv/GstFFMpegCsp:conv.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, format=(fourcc)I420, interlaced=(boolean)false, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstPlaySinkVideoConvert:vconv/GstVideoScale:scale.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, format=(fourcc)I420, interlaced=(boolean)false, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstPlaySinkVideoConvert:vconv/GstVideoScale:scale.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, format=(fourcc)I420, interlaced=(boolean)false, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstPlaySinkVideoConvert:vconv/GstVideoBalance:videobalance.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, format=(fourcc)I420, interlaced=(boolean)false, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstPlaySinkVideoConvert:vconv/GstVideoBalance:videobalance.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, format=(fourcc)I420, interlaced=(boolean)false, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstPlaySinkVideoConvert:vconv/GstFFMpegCsp:conv2.GstPad:src: caps = video/x-raw-rgb, bpp=(int)32, depth=(int)24, endianness=(int)4321, red_mask=(int)65280, green_mask=(int)16711680, blue_mask=(int)-16777216, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlaced=(boolean)false
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstPlaySinkVideoConvert:vconv/GstFFMpegCsp:conv2.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw-yuv, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, format=(fourcc)I420, interlaced=(boolean)false, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstPlaySinkVideoConvert:vconv.GstGhostPad:src: caps = video/x-raw-rgb, bpp=(int)32, depth=(int)24, endianness=(int)4321, red_mask=(int)65280, green_mask=(int)16711680, blue_mask=(int)-16777216, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlaced=(boolean)false
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstPlaySinkVideoConvert:vconv.GstGhostPad:src.GstProxyPad:proxypad16: caps = video/x-raw-rgb, bpp=(int)32, depth=(int)24, endianness=(int)4321, red_mask=(int)65280, green_mask=(int)16711680, blue_mask=(int)-16777216, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlaced=(boolean)false
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstAutoVideoSink:videosink.GstGhostPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw-rgb, bpp=(int)32, depth=(int)24, endianness=(int)4321, red_mask=(int)65280, green_mask=(int)16711680, blue_mask=(int)-16777216, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlaced=(boolean)false
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstAutoVideoSink:videosink.GstGhostPad:sink.GstProxyPad:proxypad14: caps = video/x-raw-rgb, bpp=(int)32, depth=(int)24, endianness=(int)4321, red_mask=(int)65280, green_mask=(int)16711680, blue_mask=(int)-16777216, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlaced=(boolean)false
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstAutoVideoSink:videosink.GstGhostPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw-rgb, bpp=(int)32, depth=(int)24, endianness=(int)4321, red_mask=(int)65280, green_mask=(int)16711680, blue_mask=(int)-16777216, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlaced=(boolean)false
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:vbin/GstAutoVideoSink:videosink/GstXImageSink:videosink-actual-sink-ximage.GstPad:sink: caps = video/x-raw-rgb, bpp=(int)32, depth=(int)24, endianness=(int)4321, red_mask=(int)65280, green_mask=(int)16711680, blue_mask=(int)-16777216, width=(int)512, height=(int)288, framerate=(fraction)15/1, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, interlaced=(boolean)false
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink: volume = 1.000000
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:abin/GstAutoAudioSink:audiosink/GstPulseSink:audiosink-actual-sink-pulse: volume = 1.000000
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink: mute = FALSE
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:abin/GstAutoAudioSink:audiosink/GstPulseSink:audiosink-actual-sink-pulse: mute = FALSE
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink: volume = 1.000000
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:abin/GstAutoAudioSink:audiosink/GstPulseSink:audiosink-actual-sink-pulse: volume = 1.000000
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink: mute = FALSE
/GstPlayBin2:playbin20/GstPlaySink:playsink/GstBin:abin/GstAutoAudioSink:audiosink/GstPulseSink:audiosink-actual-sink-pulse: mute = FALSE
New clock: GstPulseSinkClock
```

**3. filesrc->flvdemux->ffdec_h264**

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v filesrc location=1.flv ! flvdemux ! ffdec_h264 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFlvDemux:flvdemux0.GstPad:video: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, width=(int)33, height=(int)10, framerate=(fraction)15/1, codec_data=(buffer)014d401fffe10019674d401f9661404012d80880000003008000000f478c18c54001000468eebc80
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFlvDemux:flvdemux0.GstPad:audio: caps = audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)4, framed=(boolean)true, stream-format=(string)raw, rate=(int)22050, channels=(int)2, codec_data=(buffer)139056e5a54800
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFlvDemux:flvdemux0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
gstflvdemux.c(2442): gst_flv_demux_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFlvDemux:flvdemux0:
stream stopped, reason not-linked
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFlvDemux:flvdemux0.GstPad:audio: caps = NULL
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFlvDemux:flvdemux0.GstPad:video: caps = NULL
Freeing pipeline ...
```

**4. filesrc->flvdemux->h264parse->ffdec_h264**

```
gst-launch-0.10 -v filesrc location=1.flv ! flvdemux ! queue ! h264parse ! ffdec_h264 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is PREROLLING ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFlvDemux:flvdemux0.GstPad:video: caps = video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, pixel-aspect-ratio=(fraction)1/1, width=(int)33, height=(int)10, framerate=(fraction)15/1, codec_data=(buffer)014d401fffe10019674d401f9661404012d80880000003008000000f478c18c54001000468eebc80
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFlvDemux:flvdemux0.GstPad:audio: caps = audio/mpeg, mpegversion=(int)4, framed=(boolean)true, stream-format=(string)raw, rate=(int)22050, channels=(int)2, codec_data=(buffer)139056e5a54800
ERROR: from element /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFlvDemux:flvdemux0: Internal data stream error.
Additional debug info:
gstflvdemux.c(2442): gst_flv_demux_loop (): /GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFlvDemux:flvdemux0:
stream stopped, reason not-linked
ERROR: pipeline doesn't want to preroll.
Setting pipeline to NULL ...
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFlvDemux:flvdemux0.GstPad:audio: caps = NULL
/GstPipeline:pipeline0/GstFlvDemux:flvdemux0.GstPad:video: caps = NULL
Freeing pipeline ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays you should be using gstreamer-1, and with that you can use this pipeline:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=1.flv ! \
flvdemux ! \
h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

There is still no sound like this. To get video and sound, you need a pipeline like this:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=1.flv ! \
decodebin name=decode ! videoconvert ! autovideosink \
decode. ! audioconvert ! autoaudiosink
```

OK, that was lazy: I used `decodebin`. If you know the codecs used, you can construct the full pipeline by hand, of course:

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=1.flv ! \
flvdemux name=demux ! queue ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! videoconvert ! autovideosink \
demux. ! queue ! aacparse ! avdec_aac ! autoaudiosink
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding a caps `video/x-h264` after your demuxer.

Comment: I've tried to use some caps between elements, but caps like "video/x_h264" simply doesn't work, the log is the same to the previous that I provided.

Comment: then try running it with some higher debug-level and see what you get (unfortunately i seem to be unable to locate some flv/h.264 file, so i cannot test myself)

Comment: I've upload the FLV file.[link](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/5391695/1.flv) Would you please have a try? Actually I tried GST_DEBUG level, but the information is not very helpful to me.